# Kerberos authentication in macOS Sierra system settings

Tags: macos, authentication, kerberos, macos-sierra, pam

**Situation**

We configured a macOS Sierra machine for Kerberos authentication by:

- Adding an appropriate `/etc/krb5.conf` for our organization
- Adding the following lines at the beginning of `/etc/pam.d/authorization`

  `auth optional pam_krb5.so use_first_pass use_kcminit default_principal`

  `auth sufficient pam_krb5.so use_first_pass default_principal`

We further configured the machine for LDAP directory usage by creating a custom LDAP binding in the directory services app:

- `Users` record maps to `inetOrgPerson`
- Attribute mappings:

  - `AuthenticationAuthority` -> `uid`
  - `EMailAddress` -> `mail`
  - `FirstName` -> `givenName`
  - `NFSHomeDirectory` -> `#/Users/$uid$`
  - `PhoneNumber` -> `telephoneNumber`
  - `PrimaryGroupID` -> `gidNumber`
  - `RealName`  -> `displayName`
  - `RecordName` -> `uid`
  - `UniqueID`  -> `uidNumber`
  - `UserShell` -> `loginShell`

This gives us a working network login that authenticates against Kerberos and LDAP.

**Problem**

When network users want to change their screen saver timeout, the user authentication in the system settings does not work. The user name is greyed out and the password is not accepted. There is no visible indication about the problem source in the log files.

When you use the unlock symbol (lower left corner) for the system settings, the (non-network) admin account is accepted, but the subsequent behavior remains the same.

Adding the lines above to `/etc/pam.d/screensaver` does not solve the problem.

Is there any `/etc/pam.d` configuration file that is responsible for the system settings authentication dialog in macOS Sierra?

Is there a way to get more logging information from PAM in macOS Sierra?

Comment: MacOS Sierra already has built-in Kerberos SSO authentication to Directory Services by default; I joined my Mac to an Active Directory domain by going (on the Mac) to System Preferences > Users and Groups > Login Options > Network Account Server and filling in the appropriate information. After that, I got single sign-on to Active Directory. I don't see the added value in the route you took (and all the extra work that would have involved). I'm willing to be persuaded otherwise though.

Comment: I am not talking about an Active Directory environment. In such a case, you would be totally right. My case is a university infrastructure with Linux-based Kerberos servers, Linux-based LDAP servers and AFS file shares that only allow Kerberos authentication.

Comment: Understood.  Thanks for getting back.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what this has to do with SSO?
The pam.d settings you have listed above allow the renewal of the kerberos ticket when unlocking the screensaver, that's it.

Do you have profiles installed that are stopping the change.
I applied a profile that requires the screen saver to start after 10 minutes of activity. Even if you unlock the preference panel you cannot make the change.

If your local admin cannot make the change it would probably be a security profile that has been set.

If you change or remove the profile and then the admin can change the screensaver then you should be good.